# How do i select hierarchical data tree out of Orient DB?

Tags: orientdb

Let's say i have 3 Class in Orient DB that extends Vertex 
and 2 that extends E

The relationship is as follow:

```
Class_V1 -> edge_E1 -> Class_V2 -> edge_E2 -> Class_V3
```

How do i get, with a query , a nested tree in json?
Something like

```
+class_V1{name:abc0}
|___+class_V2 {name:abc1}
|___+class_V2 {name:abc2}
|   |___+class_V3 {name:abc3}
|   |___+class_V3 {name:abc4)
+ class_V1 {name:abc5)
```

I've tryed:

```
select name , out().name as children from class_V1
```

but i get only the first level of depth i want.

It's possible to do it in one query ?

I'm using Orientdb-enterprise edition V.2.1.5

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can have such result with just one query. You could write a [JS server-side function](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Functions.html) that aggregates results in that way. Or you could use a tabular approach, thanks to the [UNWIND](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Query.html#unwind) keyword:

```
SELECT name, out().name AS children, out().out().name AS children2
FROM class_V1
UNWIND children, children2
```

In this way you have a flat table. For more information about UNWIND, look at http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Query.html#unwind.

Comment: Uhmm i ovelooked a bit the end result :D, my fault. It's almost it, except that the record , after the first level get grouped in children1 and 2 , so now i have level 2 and 3 on the same level (inside level 1). And it make sense looking at the query. But the tree that i have to do every

Comment: has nested values that i would like to retain in one query if possible.So to recap now i have level1 with under level 2 and 3 on the same level. I hope it make sense. I've tried prevoiusly also with traverse but i couldn't expand the name property. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thanks! knowing this saved me a lot of trials. Definitely i'll go for the aggregation of results.

Comment: Wouldn't the use of an appropriate `FETCHPLAN` strategy result in a fully-materialized tree (if using 'lightweight edgets')?